# $(...).datepicker(...).data(...).selectDate is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have function that works with datepickers

Here it is

```
$(".multi_datepicker").each((key, elem) => {
  $(elem)
    .datepicker({
      language: gon.locale,
      minDate: new Date($(elem).attr("data-mindate")),
      maxDate: new Date($(elem).attr("data-maxdate")),
      autoClose: true,
      onShow: (inst, animationCompleted) => {
        if (animationCompleted) return true;
        var id = Number(inst.$el.attr("id").split("_")[2]);
        if (id < 0) return true;
        var previous = $(`#search_legs_${id - 1}_date`);
        if (previous.length == 0) return true;
        var date = previous.datepicker().data("datepicker")
          .selectedDates[0];
        if (inst.selectedDates[0] < date) inst.selectedDates = [date];
        inst.update("minDate", date);
      },
      onSelect: (dateText, inst) => {
        var no_count = Number($("#search_no_legs").val());
        var p = $("#search_legs_0_date").val();
        for (let i = 1; i < no_count; i++) {
          var leg_id = `#search_legs_${i}_date`;
          if ($(leg_id).val() < p) $(leg_id).val(p);
          p = $(leg_id).val();
        }
      }
    })
    .data("datepicker")
    .selectDate(new Date($(elem).attr("data-defaultDate")));
});
```

}

But last row cause error

> $(...).datepicker(...).data(...).selectDate is not a function

I cannot unserstood why?

How I can solve it?

Comment: I think u didn't import the jquery ui library file

Comment: Nope. It's imported@itsme

Comment: Please show a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). My guess is you didn't import jquery correctly or you don't have the class 'multi_datepicker' set.

Comment: what is that variable? try this:
`var foobar = $(...).datepicker(...).data(...);   console.log(foobar);`

Comment: <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script can u check console it is loaded correctly

Comment: The jQuery UI Datepicker doesn't have a selectDate method. Maybe you meant setDate?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using .selectDate() after creating the date picker?
It would end up something like this:

```
$(elem).datepicker(..).data(..);
$(elem).selectDate(..);
```

Comment: the datepicker's methods don't exist directly on $.fn. they either have to be called using `.datepicker('method')` or `.data('datepicker').method()`